# How do I create a shortcut for any app on desktop?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-shortcut

I think I've tried all the solutions I found on the internet, but no one worked - no force close, but nothing appears on desktop.

Now, I have this:

```
private void createShortcutOnDesktop(Application app) {

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, app.getIntentShortcut());
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, app.getName());
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.home_button));
    shortcutIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    this.sendBroadcast(shortcutIntent);
    finish();

}
```

The `app.getIntentShortcut()`:

```
public Intent getIntentShortcut() { 

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName(packageName, name);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    return i;
}
```

And in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: For reference, editing your question is enough to bump it up to the front page again.

Comment: can you please, provide full source code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved. Just change at manifest:

this:

```
<permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

to this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

Just an 'uses' ¬¬

Comment: Your code seems to produce a desktop shortcut on Execution of the program ! Is there a way by which i can create a desktop icon on installation of the app before running it.?

Comment: No you cannot because the java code has to be inside the main activity which is ran when you launch the app